# Saving Files from a Loop Without Overwrite

Tags: python, spynner

Currently my python script (which uses 'Spynner') has a loop which contains:

```
browser.load(url)
time.sleep(5)
browser.snapshot().save('example.png')
```

...but the problem is that every time the loop cycles it overwrites the previously stored image with an image of the newly rendered URL (the URL changes each time the loop is run) instead of making a new image, separate from the previous one. I have created a count but for some reason:

```
browser.snapshot().save((count)'.png')
```

doesn't seem to work. How do you use a defined count as part of a filename with .save?

Thanks

Comment: `browser.snapshot().save(str(count) + '.png')` ?

Comment: Have you tried `str(count) + '.png'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.snapshot().save('{:03d}.png'.format(count))
```

should do it. You can change the format operator (`:03d`) to a bigger number if you need to.

This will give you files with the format `000.png`, `001.png`, etc. Just using `str(count)+'.png'` will not pad the zeroes at the front, making for more difficult file handling later

Comment: Thanks for that! If I needed support for up to 10,000 file-names (instead of up to 999, within the hundreds) would I use  "{:0005d}" instead of "{:03d}"? I assumed the number of zeros and the "[number]d" were to do with the number of digits required?

Comment: No, just `{:05d}` will do it. The 0 means 'pad zeros', the 5d means a 5 digit integer

Comment: Thanks! I almost had it haha :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for counter,url in enumerate(urls):
    browser.load(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.snapshot().save(str(counter) + '.png')
```

or just set counter = 0, then run the loop, incrementing counter after each save like this : -

```
counter = 0
for url in urls:
    browser.load(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.snapshot().save(str(counter) + '.png')
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is another alternative that I will explore when I have the time